# Angular 6 Http client custom url and header

Tags: httprequest, httpclient, angular6, interceptor, base-url

I am working in an Angular 6 application and I was wondering what should be the best practice when customizing the url while sending requests to the server.

Here is the scenario:
- In my Angular project I have the environment.ts and environment.prod.ts where I added a "host" which contains the url:port of the http server (project with the controllers).
- I am creating Services to be injected in my components which will be responsible for sending requests (GETs and POSTs) to the server to retrieve data or to send updates. 
- I want to use the "host" from the environment.ts as part of the request url. So ALL my requests will have the "host" as the base url and then i can concatenate to the desired path.

I already checked a few solutions and I already implemented one of them, but I am not sure this is the right practice. I will write below what i implemented so far and then i will write some ideas, please help me understand what is the best solution (I am new at angular)

**Currently implemented:**

-> In my feature services, like LoginService, I inject the angular HttpClient. Then I simply call:

```
return this.httpService.post("/login/", creds).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        this.manager = data;
        return this.manager;
      }));
```

I created an interceptor to make changes to the url: **InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor** where I create a new instance of the HttpRequest and customize the request.url using environment.host. I also needed the interceptor to add a Header for the authentication (still not fully implemented)

```
const httpRequest = new HttpRequest(<any>request.method, environment.host + request.url, request.body);
    request = Object.assign(request, httpRequest);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer token 123',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
```

**Questions:**

> 1) This works, all my requests are changed in the interceptor as I
>   wanted, but it doesn't look like the best practice in my first look. I
>   don't like to create a new HeepRequest to be able to do this (i did it
>   to keep it immutable, I guess that's the correct way). Do you think
>   this looks good?
>
> 2) What about the Authentication being added to the Header in the interceptor? Is it ok? Most of the references I checked did this

**Other solutions:**

1) I saw some examples where a HttpClientService extends Http and each of the methods such as get and post edit the url and headers before calling super methods. But I believe this is not Angular 6 and is probably not preferrable

2) I could also create a service that receives an angular HttpClient (angular 6  HttpClientModule) instance by injection and I could implement the methods like get or post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as I didn't get any answers I will add my solution. i believe it's the best solution based on my researches.

> I used an interceptor for adding information to the header such as the
>   token bearer authentication.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

export class HttpClientInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  // intercept request to add information to the headers such as the token
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    //I decided to remove this logic from the interceptor to add the host url on the HttpClientService I created
    //const httpRequest = new HttpRequest(<any>request.method, environment.host + request.url, request.body);
    //request = Object.assign(request, httpRequest);

    var token = localStorage.getItem("bearerToken");

    if (token) {
      const newReq = request.clone(
        {
          headers: request.headers.set('Authorization',
            'Bearer ' + token)
        });

      return next.handle(newReq).pipe(
        tap(event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log("Interceptor - HttpResponse = " + event.status); // http response status code
          }
        }, error => {
          // http response status code
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log("----response----");
            console.error("status code:");
            console.error(error.status);
            console.error(error.message);
            console.log("--- end of response---");

            if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) //check if the token expired and redirect to login
              this.router.navigate(['login']);
          }
        })
      )
    }
    else {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  };
```

> For changing the url, I created a service on file
>   http-client.service.ts and got the host url from environment.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";

@Injectable({ providedIn:'root' })
export class HttpClientService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get(url: string, options?: any): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.http.get(url, options);
  }

  post(url: string, body: string, options?: any): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.http.post(url, body, options);
  }

  put(url: string, body: string, options?: any): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.http.put(url, body, options);
  }

  delete(url: string, options?: any): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.http.delete(url,options);
  }

  private updateUrl(req: string) {
    return environment.host + req;
  }
}
```

As i said, I believe this is the best approach, but feel free to add information to my question/answer.

Comment: It seems an interesting subject to me. Do you know why no one contributes on this question? what people do for theirs `base-url` in deploy time? use "environment" thing on every http call?

Comment: I really don't know why nobody added anything to this question. Seems very reasonable to me. I can say I liked my solution and I am still using it. I have a development, staging and production environment and it works really well